# How to prevent Spam at mail() when additional headers needed?

Tags: php, security, email, code-injection

I’m trying to secury my contact form from injection and found about that I should look for "\r \n". Then I thought about checking

```
if ( preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $headers )
```

But actually I need these additional headers:

```
$headers = 'From: blabla <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";

@mail($to,$subj,$msg,$headers);
```

Has anybody an Idea how to secure for mail() injection and still use the needed headers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You check your user input for `\r\n`, not the header you build yourself.

Comment: so I should check $to,  $subj and $msg? (sorry, i'm beginner and read that additional headers are causing that injections)

Comment: Yes, but also note that anybody that provides the `to` address can also add multiple addresses by separating them with commas.

Comment: @jeroen, Headers can be injected using various methods.

Comment: @Ciprian I'm not sure what you mean, there are several ways to abuse a form processor for spamming purposes but what you need to validate is your user input, not the header you build yourself.

Comment: You are right, and there are ways to sanitize the user input user PHP filters - http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php - or filters provided by the CMS or framework being used.

Comment: alright. Now I'm confused. could anybody gimme an example where I can learn from?